# Is there a 32bit Linux vsts build agent?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

I'm using on-prem 2015 vsts and it would help me to have a Ubuntu12 (32bit) vsts build agent.

I've got the 64 bit version agent working on an x64 Ubuntu16 server, but I've failed to get it working on the 32bit server. The code appears to be in GitHub but I can't work out how to build it (no makefile).

FYI - I could use the 64 bit server to run the build agent and compile on the 32bit server but I'd prefer not to if possible and I'm more or less constrained t0 a 32bit build agent as I'm actually cross compiling to arm using someone else's toolchain.

originally posted on msdn: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e89d86ec-ad42-44aa-abdf-339ba8056d8e/info-on-32bit-linux-vsts-build-agent-support?forum=tfsbuild

--

It looks like I can build 32bit binaries on the 64bit machine so this might be a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't the 32-bit Linux build agent. I submit a user voice here: [32 bit build agent (OS X, Linux),](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18536749-32-bit-build-agent-os-x-linux) you can vote and follow up it.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I might be able to build it myself, is the source there on gitHub I can only see c#?